# why this command not working?(pipe, redirection)

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe

```sh
bash-3.2$ ls | grep Makefile > a.txt | cat a.txt
```

why this don't work?? "Makefile" is exist.

Comment: ls | grep Makefile > a.txt is working. except cat a.txt

Comment: I'm implementing pipe, redirection in C

Comment: Can't see cat a.txt results

Comment: Not sure why, but a better command would be `ls | grep Makefile > a.txt && cat a.txt`. You're not piping anything through to the `cat` command from the `grep`, it's empty and pointless.

Comment: or use ls | grep Makefile | tee a.txt
The tee command will write to file but also print to stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no output from the `grep` command since you are redirecting it to a file. Therefore the pipe gets closed before the `cat a.txt` actually gets called. As per my comment, use `&&` instead of that last `|`.

Comment: A far better command would be `ls Makefile | tee a.txt`. Why `grep`?

Answer (score 0):

Do do what you want which is to save the output of a command to a file but still print to stdout use tee. (also I like to do ls -1 to make sure only one item per line is printed this is not necessary but force of habit)

```
 ls -1 | grep Makefile | tee a.txt
```